# How can I create a sprite run cycle in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

So, I'm trying to create a game using JavaFX. I know most of the basics, but I'm confused as to how I can create a sprite run cycle in JavaFX.

Spritesheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/raisY.jpg

I want to be able to call the run cycle using a method, so something like:

```java
public static void runCycle(){
// execute run cycle, I think the Animation class may help here?
// move image as well, I got that nailed down already though.
}
```

I know it's not an MRE, but I'm trying to brainstorm an idea so if you have any suggestions please let me know! :)

The image linked is the spritesheet, and if someone could help me through this that'd e great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the UI periodically to achieve this. How exactly you do this depends on the way you code the rest of the updates. If you create a game loop using `AnimationTimer`, this is probably a good place to do those updates, but for a single image a `Timeline` seems most convenient.

How you update the GUI depends on the way you want to draw the image. `Canvas` requires a different handling than `ImageView`. The former requires you to use the `drawImage` method allowing you to specify the part of the source image you want to draw, the latter requires you to update the `viewport` property.

The following example shows how to use `ImageView` and `Timeline` for this purpose:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Image image = new Image("https://i.imgur.com/K2nHT23.png");
    int height = 4;
    int width = 2;
    double spriteHeight = image.getHeight() / height;
    double spriteWidth = image.getWidth() / width;

    // create viewports to cycle through
    List<Rectangle2D> areas = new ArrayList<>(height * width);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            areas.add(new Rectangle2D(x * spriteWidth, y * spriteHeight, spriteWidth, spriteHeight));
        }
    }

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
    imageView.setViewport(areas.get(0));

    // create timeline animation cycling through viewports
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000d / 6), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        int index = 0;

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            imageView.setViewport(areas.get(index));
            index++;
            if (index >= areas.size()) {
                index = 0;
            }
        }

    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(imageView));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

(Not sure if this is the desired order of sprites in the animation.)

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly! Saved me alot of troubleshooting there haha. I appreciate the help, so thank you very much :)